# Table bigger than modal-body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to create a table inside my modal-body, but the table is displaying bigger than the modal.

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">X</button>
        <h4 id="infoTitleText" class="modal-title"><strong>Test</strong></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <p>Paragraph message</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image1" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image2" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image3" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image4" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Confirm</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to fit the table inside the modal.

Comment: Can you maybe add all of your css. Not only html

Comment: Maybe adding a working example

Comment: I'm sorry, my CSS is only bootstrap

Comment: Please see my edit - Next time try to create a [mcve] ;)

Comment: Thanks you for the edit, but it still displaying the table bigger than the modal-body. Right?

Comment: @MaxBoy yes, the question should represent your issue, not the fix. That was my edit about - to improve your code with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to use `max-width` for your images, or don't use table, but some responsive design techniques... - all depends on your needs... OK here you go

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```css
.modal-body table img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">X</button>
        <h4 id="infoTitleText" class="modal-title"><strong>Test</strong></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <p>Paragraph message</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image1" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image2" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image3" /></td>
              <td><img src="//placehold.it/300x50/0bf" height="30" alt="image4" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Confirm</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not calculate the width of images, you just set height for these images and the width will be relative with those heights.